# Use the Validator attribute (or an alternative) to validate a struct

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, fluentvalidation

We're using `"FluentValidation.AspNetCore": "6.4.0-beta3"`. The `Validate` attribute works on a class. How do we use it with a struct? The compiler complains:

> Attribute 'Validator' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class, parameter' declarations. [netstandard1.6]
>   ValidatorAttribute.ValidatorAttribute(Type validatorType)

```
[Validator(typeof(FoobarValidator))]
public struct FoobarDto
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

If it is not possible to use the `Validate` attribute on a struct, then what is the alternative way to use fluent validation with structs?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the compiler is pretty clear about the fact that you can't use this annotation on a struct.  You could do your validation "manually" :

```
FoobarDto fooBar = new FoobarDto();
FoobarValidator validator = new FoobarValidator();
ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(fooBar);
```

Or convert your struct to a class.